Select first occurrence of a value per group with condition based on the most recent record of group
I currently have a credit risk default table where default status of parties are stored. I have a business requirement to get the earliest date where default has occurred and where the most recent record has not changed status to Non-Default. I have provided some sample data to illustrate the scenario.
--Create table 
CREATE TABLE #CreditDefaults
(Party_Id nvarchar(10) null,
Party_Data_Source_Code nvarchar(3) null,
Credit_Risk_Status_Type_Group   nvarchar(10) null,
Credit_Risk_Status_Type  nvarchar(15) null,
Effective_Timestamp datetime null
)

--add some dummy data

INSERT INTO #CreditDefaults 
(Party_Id,
Party_Data_Source_Code,
Credit_Risk_Status_Type_Group,
Credit_Risk_Status_Type,
Effective_Timestamp
)

VALUES
 ('60005400',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2014-12-01 00:10:00.000')
,('60005400',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2021-06-04 00:00:01.000')
,('60054040',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2014-07-14 00:10:00.000')
,('60054040',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2014-07-14 17:36:25.000')
,('60054040',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2021-04-15 00:00:01.000')
,('60005495',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2019-02-17 00:00:00.000')
,('60005495',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Non-Default',  '2022-03-25 00:00:00.000')
,('60005660',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Default',      '2022-05-24 13:27:47.000')
,('60005672',   'MDS',  'Default',  'Non-Default',  '2020-06-26 00:00:00.000')

SELECT * FROM #CreditDefaults 


For the data above I just need to select the following records:
60005400    MDS Default Default 2014-12-01 00:10:00.000
60054040    MDS Default Default 2021-04-15 00:00:01.000
60005660    MDS Default Default 2022-05-24 13:27:47.000

Any help would be much appreciated

explain the logic behind your anted result and of course your best try

Why are you selecting the oldest 60005400 row, but the latest 60054040 row? Also, might there ever be a progression Default > Non-Default > Default? If so, would you want the original or later default row?

Depending on the expected answer for the Default > Non-Default > Default scenario, the following might be the solution.
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER()
             OVER (PARTITION BY Party_Id, Credit_Risk_Status_Type
                   ORDER BY Effective_Timestamp)
             AS rn,
         LAST_VALUE(Credit_Risk_Status_Type)
             OVER (PARTITION BY Party_Id
                   ORDER BY Effective_Timestamp
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
             AS LastStatus
   FROM #CreditDefaults 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
AND Credit_Risk_Status_Type = 'Default'
AND LastStatus <> 'Non-Default'
ORDER BY Party_Id, Effective_Timestamp

The LAST_VALUE() window function is used to identify the latest status value, while ROW_NUMBER() is used to select the earliest row for each status. Filtering for (1) status = 'Default', (2) row number = 1, and (3) latest-status <> 'Non-Default' gives us the desired results.
See this db<>fiddle for a demo with some extra test data.

Apologies for my late response. I was called away form my desk, and then had to put my daughter to bed. This gets the desired output. Indeed i selected the incorrect date for 60054040, my bad!!  Regarding the progression Default > Non-Default > Default i was told by the business this ends up affecting another table which is a different process. For now I don't need to take it into account. Thank you for the answer

(Your description and the sample output doesn't match.)
Based on your description:
SELECT cd.* FROM #CreditDefaults cd
inner join 
(select Party_Id, min(effective_TimeStamp) as earliestDate 
  from #CreditDefaults cd1 
  where not exists (select * from #CreditDefaults cd2
                    where cd1.Party_Id = cd2.Party_Id 
                      and cd2.Credit_Risk_Status_Type = 'Non-Default')
   GROUP BY Party_Id) tmp
   on cd.Party_Id = tmp.Party_Id 
  and cd.Effective_Timestamp = tmp.earliestDate ; 

DBFiddle demo

To handle cases where the first 'Default' is preceded by a 'Non-Default', I think you need a couple of additional conditions cd1.Credit_Risk_Status_Type = 'Default' and ... cd2.effective_TimeStamp > cd1.effective_TimeStamp). The OP still needs to clarify which row to select in the Default > Non-Default > Default scenario.  Fiddle with some extra test data.

@TN I don't understand what you are talking about. As I understood those having non-default would be eliminated.

See the fiddle. Compare the first and second query results for the added "9000000x" cases. The OP description was "where the most recent record has not changed status to Non-Default."

@TN mine is correct there. non-default would be eliminated.

Or if you really want only the latest not being 'Non-Default':
WITH pcreditdefaults as (
    select
        cd.*,
        row_number() over(partition by Party_Id order by Effective_Timestamp) as rn,
        row_number() over(partition by Party_Id order by Effective_Timestamp desc) as rnd
    from #CreditDefaults cd
)
select Party_Id, Party_Data_Source_Code, Credit_Risk_Status_Type_Group, Credit_Risk_Status_Type, Effective_Timestamp
from pcreditdefaults d
where rn = 1
and not exists(
    select 1 from pcreditdefaults d1 
    where d.Party_Id = d1.Party_Id and d1.rnd = 1 
        and d1.Credit_Risk_Status_Type = 'Non-Default'
)
;


SELECT 
  Party_Id
  ,Party_Data_Source_Code
  ,Credit_Risk_Status_Type_Group
  ,ts_max = MAX(Effective_Timestamp)
FROM #CreditDefaults co
WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL FROM #CreditDefaults ci
                  WHERE co.Party_Id = ci.Party_Id 
                        AND ci.Credit_Risk_Status_Type = 'Non-Default' )
GROUP BY 
  Party_Id
  ,Party_Data_Source_Code
  ,Credit_Risk_Status_Type_Group

